# PPM image reading error in C++

Tags: c++

i want to copy the contents of the datas pointer-array to my buffer.Bug when i try to compile this i get the following error :

```
Error C3861: 'copy': identifier not found
```

Please keep in mind that this is for an assignment so i'd appreciate it if you just explained what i've done wrong and not just posting a code that i can copy.

Here's the code :

```
    void setData(const float * & datas)
    {
        buffer = std::copy(datas, datas + (width*height * 3), buffer);
    }
```

PS: I can't include anything to my file.

Thanks!

Comment: Please excuse the title,i tried to make another post yesterday but i changed my mind,so i guess the title  somehow stayed like that xD

Comment: and you've included the `<algorithm>` header ?

Comment: Nothing included in this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using `std::copy()` you need to include the header `<algorithm>` (that seems to be your problem, given the error message C3861).

Furthermore, the destination have a type compatible with the source.  So buffer should be an iterator to a container of `float`.

If nothing can be included (homework?), then:

- if `<memory>` is included, then consider using `std::uninitialized_copy()` instead
- else, you have to make your own manual for-loop to implement yourself the copy

Comment: It's for homework,i think i've said so in the question,Thanks for answering so fast <3

Comment: 1 more thing,isn't my manual for-loop way slower than using std::copy() ? Thanks again!

Comment: Not necessarily, at least with a modern optimizing compiler